# mode: 0o666 in file system methods, what is it?

Tags: node.js

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

It mentions the option `mode` with the value `0o666`. As you can read if you click the link there is no real description of what this.

I am presuming it is the file permission to be set. However I'm not used to seeing `0o666`. Am I correct that it is the file permission and if so, what does `0o666` stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was correct it was octal file permissions for the file. `0o` in ES6 represents octal.

http://www.2ality.com/2015/04/numbers-math-es6.html

Comment: And "666" represents the file mode of the beast.

Comment: @robertklep normally I wouldn't post anything here but I laughed WAY too hard at that